# Is Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics a journal or book series

Tags: reference-request, foundations

I'd like to know if *Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics* by Elsevier is a journal or book series. The reason I am asking is that its recent issues look like a book series. However, its issues of the 1960s published papers "Assigning Probabilities to Logical Formulas" by Scott and Krauss as well as "Probabilistic inference and the concept of total evidence" by Suppes. So it also looks like a journal.

Comment: This seems more like an English language question than a mathematical one.

Comment: It is definitely a book series, a book series that I have 7 or 8 volumes of on my bookshelves and a book series that I've seen for several decades in many university libraries. Possibly what is confusing you about the papers you cited, at least when you aren't actually looking at the physical versions of the papers themselves, is that some of the volumes are collections of conference papers or other collections of papers (e.g. [Volume 90](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444863885) is the well-known "Handbook of Mathematical Logic" edited by Jon Barwise).

Comment: By the way, I can't believe how expensive even the paperback version of Volume 90 is ($421.99 for a paperback copy). I think I paid about 1/6 this much for a NEW copy in the early 1990s . . .

Comment: I think there is a free download of pdf on the website of Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics of Elsevier.

Comment: @Eugene Zhang: *I think there is a free download of pdf on the website of Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics of Elsevier.* --- I tried a chapter in [Volume 90](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/90) and got this message: "Note: Your selections could not be downloaded as you are not subscribed to that content." So it seems that there are NOT free downloads -- the books and chapters are behind a paywall.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro, you need an institution account to download them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [web page](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics) for the series clearly labels it as a book series.

The two papers you mention, "Assigning Probabilities to Logical Formulas" by Scott and Krauss and "Probabilistic inference and the concept of total evidence" by Suppes are actually chapters of [Volume 43](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/43/suppl/C), *Aspects of Inductive Logic*, edited by Hintikka and Suppes.

Book chapters in edited volumes are often difficult to distinguish from research papers. Sometimes they are in fact research papers, in the case when the volume is conference proceedings from a conference where the paper was presented. In the specific case of Volume 43, the preface tells us that 8 of the 14 chapters are papers originally presented at an International Symposium on Confirmation and Information in Helsinki in 1965. However, neither of the papers you mention, by Scott and Krauss and by Suppes, are among those listed in the preface as being presented in Helsinki. Presumably these authors (one of whom is an editor of the volume) were invited to submit work to the volume in preparation, to supplement the Hensinki proceedings.

---

In the comments below, the OP raised the issue of the proper way to cite these book chapters. Bibliography styles vary, but a good example is the citation of the Scott and Krauss paper on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on [Interpretations of Probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/ENTRIES/probability-interpret/).

> Scott D., and Krauss P.,1966, “Assigning Probabilities to Logical Formulas”, in Aspects of Inductive Logic, J. Hintikka and P. Suppes (eds.), Amsterdam: North-Holland, 219–264.

In BibTeX, the template you use for a book chapter in an edited volume is [@incollection](https://www.bibtex.com/t/template-incollection/) (whereas you use @article for a journal article and @inproceedings for a conference paper).

Comment: So the papers by Scott/Krauss and Suppes are conference papers, not published by journals, right?

Comment: @EugeneZhang They are book chapters, which is a separate category of academic publishing than conference papers and journal articles.

Comment: But from the citation point of view, they are more like papers than book chapters because normally books are cited with titles. The two papers are (generally) cited by their names followed by "Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics". So it looks like they are articles because "Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics" is not a book.

Comment: I'm not sure if these papers are generally cited by their names followed by "Studies in Logic...", but this is not how I would cite them. I did a quick search for the Scott and Krauss paper on Google Scholar, and the first few sources that I checked  all cited it properly as a book chapter (with the key word "in" before a citation for the book). Here are some examples: [one](https://plato.stanford.edu/ENTRIES/probability-interpret/) [two](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4953.pdf) [three](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=71f4bdd0b59d68076419d81cca12dda49edd3b81).

Comment: @EugeneZhang I've added to my answer to address citing book chapters.

Comment: @ Alex Kruckman, thanks a lot. BTW, is "Probabilistic inference and the concept of total evidence" by Suppes in the same book chapter (same citation) as Scott and Krauss?

Comment: It's a different chapter in the same book. So you'd use the same citation format, but change out the authors, title, and page numbers.